# How to call C++ funtion from Fortran 77 using std::vector as arguments?

Tags: c++, vector, fortran, subroutine

I have to replace some Fortran subroutines with C++ functions. Since the literature is poor, I am stuck with a problem like the following one.

My code always throws an error:

> Program received signal SIGSEGV: Segmentation fault - invalid memory reference.

This is my Fortran code:

```
  PROGRAM vector_adder
  IMPLICIT NONE

  INTEGER,DIMENSION(3) :: a,b,c
  INTEGER :: i

  !C fill vectors with values
  DO i = 1,3
      a(i) = i
      b(i) = i
  END DO

  CALL ADD_VECTORS(a,b,c)

  WRITE(*,'(I5,I5,I5)') (c(i),i =1,3)

  STOP
  END PROGRAM
```

A working C code:

```
void add_vectors_(int (*a)[3], int (*b)[3], int (*c)[3])
{
    for(int i = 0; i<3 ; i++)
    {
        (*c)[i] =(*a)[i] + (*b)[i];
    }
}
```

And I would like a similar one in C++:

```
extern "C" void add_vectors_(std::vector<int> *a, std::vector<int> *b, std::vector<int> *c)
{
    for(int i = 0; i<a->size() ; i++)
    {
        (*c)[i] =(*a)[i] + (*b)[i];
    }
}
```

Comment: It will be easier to stick with the C-style function call in C++ also. I don't think there is a portable of interfacing with a `std::vector` object from FORTRAN.

Comment: More generally, you cannot pass a C++ object to Fortran, no matter which C++ class it is.  `std::vector<int>` is not special in this sense.

Comment: You, can pass around a pointer to anything, be it a C++ class or not.

Comment: The ISO_C_BINDING in fortran means that it is easier to have mixed language code. If the fortran version works, then rewriting it in C does not seem to be the most optimum approach.

Answer (score -3, accepted):

You are mixing your `fortran`, `C` lingo of `vector` which refers to a collection of `int`s in contiguous memory location i.e an `array` with `C++`'s `std::vector`. `std::vector` is a separate container class altogether and needs construction - refer to the [documentation](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/vector/vector/vector/)

Answer (score 4):

Here is C++ code you can call from FORTRAN

```
extern "C" void add_vectors_(int(*a)[3], int(*b)[3], int(*c)[3])
{
    for (size_t i = 0; i<3; i++)
    {
        (*c)[i] = (*a)[i] + (*b)[i];
    }
}
```

`std::vector<>` does not have a portable interface to allow it to be called from other non-C++ code; since it's a template, doing so would be difficult.  (In fact, there can even be problems with `std::vector` compatibility between different versions of a compiler, or different compilers on the same system.)

You might like something similar to C++17's [`string_view`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/string/basic_string_view) for `vector<>`, but such a thing isn't part of the Standard Library.  Note that many of the Standard Library routines take *begin* and *end* arguments which work well with C-style code.